# Angular location search does not work with &

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[/course-home#/search?q=my%20lab%20%26%20mastering&%20kamal&ref=%2Ftab%2Factive](http:///course-home#/search?q=my%20lab%20%26%20mastering&%20kamal&ref=%2Ftab%2Factive)

```
$scope.keyword = $location.search().q;
```

In my angular app when I search for "my lab & mastering" $location.search().q returns only "my lab" and does not return full string. after the **"&"** it does not work properly. What is the best way to get query string from above URL ?

Comment: can you provide fiddle please

Answer (score 1):

create a `$scope` which is set to an array of symbols. Include in this array the **&** symbol and add it to your data.

I think that is because it has the url encoding of  **%26**. Check out the W3C cheat sheet about URL encoding to see how exactly to reference them:

[URL encoding cheat sheet](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, and the issue was URL encoding not done properly.

```
$location.url('/search?q=' + searchText + '&ref=' + $location.$$path);
```

***To fix the issue need to encode the searchText variable***

```
$location.url('/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchText) + '&ref=' + $location.$$path);
```